# how to create multiple files in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

Why is this code not writing to different files?

---file name: "file.c". c

```
  int main(){
  // skipped rest of the code
  FILE * pfile;
  while(i<25)
  {
        sprintf(mytext,"%d.txt", i); // trying to make mytext1.txt, mytext2.txt ...
        pfile = fopen ("mytextd.txt","w"); // trying to write in each files "confuse here"
        printf("eneter in server recieve");
        if(pfile != NULL)
        {
    //    while(i<25)
    //    {
            read(connfd,sendBuff,sizeof(sendBuff));
            fputs(sendBuff,pfile);
            fputs(sendBuff,stdout);
            i++;
    //    } 
          fclose (pfile);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should decide whether this is text or binary, and be consistent about it.  (1) `read` reads byte arrays -- not strings -- so (1a) it has no concept of a "line", and (1b) it won't terminate the array for you.  And (2) `fputs` writes strings -- not naked arrays -- so (2a) an unterminated array, not being a string, provokes UB, and (2b) your files will almost definitely end up corrupted all to hell (missing chunks, extra garbage, etc etc), because NULs (or their absence) will make it act funny.

Comment: read (...) and other are part of code. I understand your point. But i am trying to make files having different name whether it is bin or txt i am just trying to  make file.

Comment: Then, erm...maybe you shouldn't be using a literal string as the filename?  If you only ever `fopen("mytextd.txt", "w")`, then you'll only ever open `mytextd.txt`...

Comment: BTW, google "unix tee".

Comment: actually i am trying that what ever "i" is it should make file name as mytext1.txt, mytext2.txt and so on.... and since it is in loop it should also write something in file.

Comment: So `sprintf(mytext, "mytext%d.txt", i);` (and of course, make sure `mytext` is  -- or points to -- a big enough array).

Comment: i first thought for array but later found it of no use. i did nt understand for in what direction u are saying for big array.? because i feel this is simple logic that joins "i" with "mytext" creating name "mytext1.txt".

Comment: I gave the very statement that would do that.  You just have to make sure `mytext` is big enough to hold the resulting string.

Answer (score 5):

You loop keeps writing to the same file "mytestd.txt" because you are using that string constant instead of the variable `mytext` that you just wrote the desired filename into.

You probably mean

```
pfile = fopen (mytext,"w");
```

Comment: eric i did apply this and found this is correct but file is not occurring with any single name. any idea ??

Comment: Are you looking in the right place for the file?  You do not specify a path, so the file will be written to the current directory.  Can you step through in a debugger?  Is the file in fact being opened? (That is, do you get to the point where you start writing to it)?

Comment: this is ubuntu and all files are in one folder.